# Automatic zoom on object in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, selection, force-layout

I have a force directed graph and I implemented an autocomplete in order to highlight a node. Basically, once you select a node it is colored in red. I would now like to "zoom" on this node, which is change my window to be 400% the size of the node and the node should be centered in it.

Here are the relevant samples of my code: (or you can directly go to the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRXsK/2/) I setup.)

First the code used to create the `svg` element:

```
var w = 4000,
    h = 3000;
var vis = d3.select("#mysvg")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("id","svg")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr("viewBox","0 0 "+w+" "+h)
    .attr("perserveAspectRatio","xMinYMid")
    .append('svg:g')
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .append('svg:g');
```

Then, as an example, the function used to redraw the directed graph on "normal" zoom.

```
function redraw() {
    trans=d3.event.translate;
    scale=d3.event.scale;
    vis.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + trans + ")"
            + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

Here are the nodes of my graph:

```
vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id;})
    .enter().append("g")
    .append("circle")
        .attr("id", function(d){return "circle-node-"+ d.id})
        .attr("fill","white")
        .attr("r","50px")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width","2px");
```

And finally here is my autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: nodes; //...
        select: function( event, ui){
            // ...
            vis.selectAll("#circle-node-"+ui.item.value)
                .transition()
                .attr("fill", "red")
        }

    })
});
```

I tried to put as little code as possible so, sorry if I forgot something.

**Update** Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRXsK/2/) illustrating where I am for now.

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be really helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling I set up a jsFiddle as requested. Thanks for any help. http://jsfiddle.net/wRXsK/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scaling and translation should be handled in the same function where you color the node red. You haven't really described how exactly you want the zoom to behave, but probably the easiest way is to apply `translate` and `scale` to the `g` element containing the graph.

I've changed your jsfiddle to do this; result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wRXsK/10/). I've assumed that by "400% the size of the node" you mean that the node should be magnified 400%? I've introduced a variable for the zoom factor if you want to change it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the demo. That's what I want with still a small problem, after selecting a node, when I zoom again on something the position "resets". Is there a way to make d3 think that automatically zooming on a point was the same as if the user had zoomed on it?

Comment: Sure, you simply need to set the same translate and scale values for the zoom behavior. See http://jsfiddle.net/wRXsK/11/

Comment: Thank you very much! I just recommend futur users to verify that the attribute "cx" and "cy" exist, as I had a problem with it.